# Retrieving info from a file

Tags: php, filenames

This code retrieves information from another site:

```
<?php


    $location = $ident;

get_taf($location);

function get_taf($location) {
$fileName = "ftp://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/forecasts/taf/stations/$location.TXT";
    $taf = '';
    $fileData = @file($fileName);

    if ($fileData != false) {
        list($i, $date) = each($fileData);

        $utc = strtotime(trim($date));
        $time = date("D, jS M Y Hi",$utc);

        while (list($i, $line) = each($fileData)) {
            $taf .= ' ' . trim($line);
            }
        $taf = trim(str_replace('  ', ' ', $taf));
        }


if(!empty($taf)){
    echo "Issued: $time Z
    <br><br>
    $taf";
    } else {
    echo 'TAF not available';
    }
}

?>
```

What its **suppose** to look like:

```
 TAF KLBX 160541Z 1606/1706 15009KT P6SM FEW009 BKN013 OVC030 
 FM160900 15005KT P6SM SCT010 BKN035 
 FM161600 16010KT P6SM VCSH SCT012 BKN030 
 FM161900 18012KT P6SM SCT025 BKN040 
 FM170000 16005KT P6SM SCT012 BKN022
```

What it ends up looking like:

```
TAF KLBX 160541Z 1606/1706 15009KT P6SM FEW009 BKN013 OVC030 FM160900 15005KT P6SM SCT010 BKN035 FM161600 16010KT P6SM VCSH SCT012 BKN030 FM161900 18012KT P6SM SCT025 BKN040 FM170000 16005KT P6SM SCT012 BKN022
```

How do I maintain the spacing with the rows???

It is putting all the info on 1 line and it looks like a paragraoh instead a list.

Thanks

Comment: If each new line begins with FMxxxxxx just insert the <br/> using preg_replace, e.g.: `preg_replace('/(FM)/', '<br />FM', $taf)`. If the file already contains the newlines you can use `nl2br($taf)` to convert `\n` (newline in text files) to `<br>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output contains newline bytes, but in webpages those line breaks are usually treated as regular spacing characters and not as an actual line break (the `br` tag is used for hard breaks instead). PHP has a function to convert line breaks to `br` tags called [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php), so you could do this:

```
$taf = nl2br(trim(str_replace('  ', ' ', $taf)), false);
```

Since you're trimming the line endings of every line you'll also have to modify something to either preserve them (by using `trim` with two parameters or by using just `ltrim`) or re-add them manually like this:

```
$taf .= ' ' . trim($line) . "\n";
```

You could also append the `<br>` tags directly, that would save you the conversion. Another possibility would be to just preserve/add the line endings and wrap the output in a `<pre>` section, this will eliminate the need of break-tags.

Comment: I replaced the line of code with your suggestion, it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the following line

```
 $taf .= ' ' . trim($line);
```

Using the PHP End of Line constant, like so:

```
 $taf .= ' ' . trim($line).PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: It's a webpage, so this alone won't be sufficient. The output needs to be marked as preformatted using `<pre>` or use explicit `<br>` breaks.