# How to store data retrieve from php file with java

Tags: java, php, arrays

my question is how do we **store** data from php file at web using java 
(i can view the php file but cant store it into my array variable). may this benefit other.

```
//http://sampleonly.com.my/getInfo.php //this url is not exist. just for example

<?php
echo("Ridzuan");
echo("split");
echo("Malaysia");
echo("split");
?>
// i want to get the echo "Ridzuan" and "Malaysia". i dont want echo "split".
```

below is my current code

```
    URL connectURL = new URL("http://sampleonly.com.my/getInfo.php");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(connectURL.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);

        //array below should store input from .php file after i thrown "split" text
        String[] strArray2 = inputLine.split(Pattern.quote("split"));

    in.close();
```

error output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

i have refer to this question, [Retrieving info from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733122/retrieving-info-from-a-file) but confuse to understand the code. perhap any good people here can provide me with valid code on how to store echo data from php file to my java array variable.

thanks in advance folk.

**ANSWER** credit to JJPA

```
    URL connectURL = new URL("http://vmalloc.in/so.php");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(connectURL.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){     
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        sb.append(inputLine);
    }
    String[] strArray2 = sb.toString().split(Pattern.quote("split"));
    System.out.println(strArray2[0]);
    System.out.println(strArray2[1]);

    in.close();
```

output result:

```
    Ridzuan
    Malaysia
```

just like what i wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should get that exception in `inputLine`. To know I recommend you to debug your code.

As a solution try the below code.

```
 URL connectURL = new URL("http://vmalloc.in/so.php");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            connectURL.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        sb.append(inputLine);
    }
    // array below should store input from .php file after i thrown "split"
    // text
    String[] strArray2 = sb.toString().split("split");
    System.out.println(strArray2);
    in.close();
```

Comment: thanks JJPA, it works and i appreciate your effort. i now know inputLine return null and cause the error. i also put my working code under my question so other can benefit. thanks to other guy who have also help.

Answer (score 0):

Use flower bases for while block. Otherwise you are using a `null` `inputLine` after the while  block. That is because you are leaving the loop when `inputLine` is null. And hence, when tried to use the same, it threw a `NullPointerException`.

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(inputLine);

   //array below should store input from .php file after i thrown "split" text
   String[] strArray2 = inputLine.split(Pattern.quote("split"));
   // do whatever you want with this array
} // while
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NullPointerException because your inputLine is NULL. You are running the loop until the inputLine is NULL and then after the loop is terminated, you are using that NULL variable to get the php result. Instead, store it in a temporary variable, either String or array according to your need.

For example, if you need to store it in a string, you can do it as follows

```
String inputLine, temp="";
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
   temp.concat(inputLine);
   System.out.println(inputLine);
}
```

And then use the variable temp to access the result.